# Swift stop unloading of table view cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm making a table view that downloads an image for the cell off the web, every time the cell is loaded.

This proves a problem though, as when you scroll down then up again, the cells are reloaded.

Is there any way to stop the unloading of cells, and control how many cells are loaded when the view appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose that instead of trying to stop your `UITableView` from reusing cells, which would decrease performance, you store the images you download, using `NSCache` for example.

`NSCache` works the same way as a `Dictionary` - with key value pairs. The main difference however is it incorporates various auto-removal policies, which ensure that it does not use too much of the system’s memory. Here's the documentation on `NSCache`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html

Using this method: when you're setting up your `UITableViewCell`, you could check if an image has been downloaded for that `NSIndexPath`. If an image hasn't been downloaded you download it and add it to the cache once its finished, otherwise you use your cache and get the image from there.